# Журнал медленных запросов MySQL

Tags: mysql

Добрый день, я сделал так, что MySQL записывал в журнал медленные запросы, выполнение которых происходит более 2-х секунд.

Вот это содержимое на данный момент:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.13.10.2-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 140216 15:10:09
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 5.453749  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 64394  Rows_examined: 64394
use travian;
SET timestamp=1392556209;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `tx5_odata`;
# Time: 140216 15:10:15
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 4.653896  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 65006  Rows_examined: 65006
SET timestamp=1392556215;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `tx5_units`;
# Time: 140216 15:10:26
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 11.289096  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 641601  Rows_examined: 641601
SET timestamp=1392556226;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `tx5_wdata`;
# Time: 140216 15:13:41
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 5.317493  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 64394  Rows_examined: 64394
SET timestamp=1392556421;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `tx5_odata`;
# Time: 140216 15:13:48
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 6.602040  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 65006  Rows_examined: 65006
SET timestamp=1392556428;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `tx5_units`;
# Time: 140216 15:14:00
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 11.427378  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 641601  Rows_examined: 641601
SET timestamp=1392556440;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `tx5_wdata`;
```

А что делать дальше? Помогите, пожалуйста, советами, как оптимизировать эти запросы и понять, что тут написано... Потому как следующая запись не совсем понятна:

```
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM tx5_wdata;
```

Comment: Так вам надо сам запрос писать в журнал, а тут только метаданные.

Comment: И как писать сам запрос в журнал?

Comment: @eprivalov1, у вас запросы идут без where. вы уверены что вам нужны сразу все 65к записей?

Comment: @ua6xh

> SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `tx5_wdata`;

я туплю или это все-таки оно?

Comment: @Fike, оно, только `/*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */` выкинуть надо, и получаем текст запроса. Тупит тут, как раз, @ua6xh.

Comment: мне так кажется это sql hint, no cache, по сути вопроса - надо найти где это вызывается и 

  * убрать `/*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */` преобразовать сами запросы, чтобы не все записи все время выбирать.

космос подсказывает мне, что это бэкап базы данных, наверное ежедневный. тогда ничего убирать не надо, и понять, мешает ли оно чем нить или нет.

Comment: если записанный в кэш размер выборки больше, чем query_cache_limit, то есть результат выборки будет большим, стоит выполнять его с директивой *SQL_NO_CACHE*

Answer (score 1):

У вас три медленных запроса

```
SELECT * FROM `tx5_odata`;
```

Извлекает и отправляет клиенту все содержимое таблицы `tx5_odata` - 65006 записей.

```
SELECT * FROM `tx5_units`;
```

Извлекает и отправляет клиенту все содержимое таблицы `tx5_odata` - 641601 записей.

```
SELECT * FROM `tx5_wdata`;
```

Извлекает и отправляет клиенту все содержимое таблицы `tx5_odata` - 
64394 записей.

Запись `/*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */` просто сообщает, что результирующая таблица не помещается в кэш (он либо отключен, либо размер результат слишком велик для размещения в нем).

В любом случае это не нормально, когда вы запросом извлекаете все содержимое таблицы. Возможно, можно переработать логику программы таким образом, чтобы из базы данных извлекалась лишь часть при помощи ключевых слов `LIMIT` и `OFFSET`. Размер результирующей таблицы будет на порядки меньше и запросы будут выполняться быстрее.